# Spring MVC 3 - Form object with a Map property not binding key/value pairs on form submit

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm trying to bind an object with a Map field that is initialized on GET for rendering several checkbox tags.  All of the checkboxes show when the form is created but when it is submitted, none of the Map entries in my MessageForm (model attribute) object are bound (map size = 0).  Before I added this map field, other fields (Message) were getting set fine. How do I get the MessageForm.hierarchySelections field to get set with all of the entries that were populated in the GET request?

unitNode.jsp (VIEW_MESSAGE_FORM):

```
<div class="nodeContainer">
    <div class="nodeHeader">
        <form:checkbox path="hierarchySelections['${node.code}']"/>
        <form:label path="hierarchySelections['${node.code}']">
            ${node.name}
        </form:label>
    </div>
    <div class="nodeChildren">
        <c:forEach var="node" items="${node.children}">
            <c:set var="node" value="${node}" scope="request"/>
            <jsp:include page="unitNode.jsp"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

MessageForm.java:

```
public class MessageForm {
    private Message message;
    private Map<String, Boolean> hierarchySelections = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();    
    // getters and setters
}
```

MessageFormController.java (excerpt):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message/new")
public String newMessage(final Model model) {
    final MessageForm messageForm = new MessageForm();

    // get the root hierarchy node
    final Node rootNode = hierarchyService.getNodeHierarchy();
    messageForm.getHeirarchy(rootNode);

    final Stack<Node> nodeList = new Stack<Node>();
    nodeList.add(rootNode);

    final Map<String, Boolean> hierarchySelections = messageForm.getHierarchySelections();
    while (!nodeList.isEmpty()) {
        final Node node = nodeList.pop();

        // set the selection status to false/unchecked
        hierarchySelections.put(node.getCode(), Boolean.FALSE);

        // add all children organization units to the stack
        for (final Node nodeChild : node.getChildren()) {
            nodeList.add(nodeChild);
        }
    }   
    model.addAttribute("messageForm", messageForm);
    return VIEW_MESSAGE_FORM;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/message/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createMessage(@Valid final MessageForm messageForm, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { // TODO
    } else {
        messageCenterService.createMessage(messageForm.getMessage());
    }  
    return VIEW_MESSAGE_FORM;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that checkbox serialization works not that way you expect.

Unchecked checkbox elements are not submitted, when it's checked text from value attribute will be sended.

So first of all, use Firebug/Chrome debugger(Network tab) to monitor information sended to server from browser.